# update and insert query in spring data jpa

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

i am making a rest api in which i have to update on a id basis and insert data without id bases in a table via spring data .but i am finding a error in both conditions it runs insert query only update is not working

repository file
@Repository
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository {
    CustomerEntity save(CustomerEntity customerEntity);
    CustomerEntity findById(int id);

access manager file

public CustomerDO create(CustomerDO customerReqDO){CustomerEntity customerEntity = null;
CustomerDO customerResDO=new CustomerDO();
        if (null != customerReqDO.getId()) {
            customerEntity = customerRepository.findById(Integer.parseInt(customerReqDO.getId()));
                if (null != customerEntity) {

```
            if(null != customerReqDO.getName())
                customerEntity.setName(customerReqDO.getName());

            if(null != customerReqDO.getPhone())
                customerEntity.setPhone(customerReqDO.getPhone());

            if(null != customerReqDO.getEmail())

                customerEntity.setEmail(customerReqDO.getEmail());

            if(null != customerReqDO.getPassword())
                customerEntity.setPassword(customerReqDO.getPassword());
            //if(null !=customerReqDO.getCredits())
                //customerReqEntity.setCredits(customerReqDO.getCredits());

            customerEntity =customerRepository.save(customerEntity);

          }else{
                    customerResDO.setError("Invalid Customer id "+customerReqDO.getId());
          }}else{
    customerEntity=new CustomerEntity();                    
    customerEntity.setName(customerReqDO.getName());
    customerEntity.setPhone(customerReqDO.getPhone());
    customerEntity.setEmail(customerReqDO.getEmail());

    //customerReqEntity.setFacebookID(customerReqDO.getFacebookID());
    customerEntity.setPassword(customerReqDO.getPassword());
    //customerReqEntity.setCredits(customerReqDO.getCredits());

    customerEntity =customerRepository.save(customerEntity);

            }if(null != customerEntity){
                customerResDO.setId(String.valueOf(customerEntity.getId()));
                customerResDO.setName(customerEntity.getName());
                customerResDO.setPhone(customerEntity.getPhone());
                customerResDO.setEmail(customerEntity.getEmail());
                customerResDO.setPassword(customerEntity.getPassword());
                //deliveryLocationResponseDO.setDeliverytimes(Arrays.asList(deliveryLocationEntity.getDeliverytimes()));
            }
    return customerResDO;

}



controller
```

@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
    @PostMapping()
    public CustomerResponseDTO register(@RequestBody CustomerUpdateRequestDTO registerRequestDTO) {
        CustomerDO customerReqDO = new CustomerDO();
        CustomerResponseDTO loginResponseDTO = new CustomerResponseDTO();
        customerReqDO.setName(registerRequestDTO.getName());
        customerReqDO.setEmail(registerRequestDTO.getEmail());
        customerReqDO.setPhone(registerRequestDTO.getPhone());
        customerReqDO.setPassword(registerRequestDTO.getPassword());

```
    CustomerDO  customerResDO = customerLoginManagerImpl.insert(customerReqDO);

    if(null != customerResDO.getError()){
        loginResponseDTO.setError(customerResDO.getError());
    }else{


    loginResponseDTO.setSucess(true);
}

    return loginResponseDTO;
}
```

Comment: implementation manager

Comment: public CustomerDO insert(CustomerDO customerReqDO)
 {
  CustomerDO customerResDO = customerAccessManager.create(customerReqDO);
  return customerResDO;
 }

Comment: May I know what you are expecting here?. Would you like to know how to insert and update in sping data jpa ? just call the save method of the JpaRepository.

Comment: no ,update query is not working i was want to know whats the error now its working fine and error was in controller part where i have not set  'id' thanks for your response Barath

Answer (score 0):

Using Criteria from Hibernate :

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

String query= "update TableName c set c.attribute= :newAttribute where c.id=:id";
int updatedEntities = s.createQuery( query )
    .setString( "newAttribute ", newAttribute )
    .setString( "id", id)
    .executeUpdate();
tx.commit();
session.close();
```